# CSV Column Separation using PHP

Tags: php, csv

this is how my url looks in the csv. it has been separated by vertical bar(|).

> http://www.example.com/ebay/test/HID_Bulb_Color.jpg|http://www.www.abc.net/ebay/test/10000K-1.jpg|http://www.www.abc.net/ebay/test/12000K-1.jpg

I want to break it down separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

```
<?php

$parts = explode("|", $string);
```

**[Live demo](http://codepad.org/sB2yK1oZ)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_getcsv() where you an set the separator yourself.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php